# Check if variable is empty, if its empty then restart localhost

Tags: powershell

Its a fairly basic thing I'm trying to do. I have two SQL queries that populate the variables below. I want the queries to run until they are empty then reboot the localhost.

```
Do {
 database Query that populates two variables. If both variables are empty then reboot the local host. 

}
until($jobquery -and $testQuery)

{
 restart-computer -computername "localhost" -force
}
```

Comment: `until (!$jobquery -and !$testQuery)` or `until ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($jobquery) -and [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($testQuery))`

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean:

```
until(!$jobquery -and !$testQuery)
```

Or maybe a good suggestion would be to add try catch error handling so it will look something like this:

```
Do{
    try{
       database Query that populates two variables. If both variables are empty then reboot the local host. 
    }catch{
        if(!$jobquery){
            Write-Host "Unable to do query because jobquery is empty. Error: $($_.Exception.Message)" -ForegroundColor Red
        }elseif(!$testQuery){
            Write-Host "Unable to do query because testquery is empty. Error: $($_.Exception.Message)" -ForegroundColor Red
        }else{
            Write-Host "Unable to do query because the following error: $($_.Exception.Message)" -ForegroundColor Red
        }
    }
}until(!$jobquery -and !$testQuery)

{
 restart-computer -computername "localhost" -force
}
```

Hope this helps!